# Set value to text-area when button clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

This is no error found, how do I set the value to text-area when button clicked?

> default value 332 and when button clicked value changed to ROUNDUP(332)

text-area code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>{{getEntityMeta('function').fieldDescription}}</mat-label>
   <textarea matInput [placeholder]="getEntityMeta('function').fieldDescription" type="text"
       name="function" [(ngModel)]="salaryformulaEntity.function" 
       #function="ngModel" [disabled]="salaryformulaEntity.isUnmodified()" [required]="getEntityMeta('function').mandatory" 
       [wynixMandatory]="getEntityMeta('function').mandatory" [wynixMaxLength]="getEntityMeta('function').maxLength"
       wynixSpecialCharacter></textarea>
   <mat-error *ngIf="getErrorMessage(function)">{{getErrorMessage(function)}}</mat-error>
   <mat-hint align="end">{{function.value?.length || 0}}/{{getEntityMeta('function').maxLength}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

button-logic code:

```
selectComponent(): void {
    for (let index = this.componentLov.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      const component: LOVItem = this.componentLov[index];

      if (component.options.selected) {


        component.options.selected = false;
      }
    }

    this.filterComponentsLov();
    this.filterFunctionsLov();
    this.filterFormulasLov();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to format better the text-area code and to specify when the error occurred on the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the text area value at the click action level: inside your button logic add
salaryformulaEntity.function = "newValue"