# How to set value into text-area without triggering

Tags: angular

i have a text-area and i want to set text-area value when button clicked. but i must trigger the text area with typing some word.

if this possible to set value without trigerring?

**TextArea code :**

```
<textarea  class="md-height" matInput [placeholder]="getEntityMeta('function').fieldDescription" type="text" name="function" [(ngModel)]="salaryformulaEntity.function" #function="ngModel" [disabled]="salaryformulaEntity.isUnmodified()" [required]="getEntityMeta('function').mandatory" [wynixMandatory]="getEntityMeta('function').mandatory" [wynixMaxLength]="getEntityMeta('function').maxLength"></textarea>
```

**Logic to set value**

```
  selectComponent() : void{
    for (let index = this.componentLov.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      const component: LOVItem = this.componentLov[index];

      if(component.options.selected){
        if(this.chipList.selected){
          this.salaryformulaEntity.function = this.salaryformulaEntity.function.concat(this.chipList.selected.value + "(" + component.options.code +")" + " ") ;
        }else {
          this.salaryformulaEntity.function =  this.salaryformulaEntity.function.concat(component.options.code + " ");
        }
        component.options.selected = false;    
      }
         this.filterComponentsLov();
         this.filterFunctionsLov();
         this.filterFormulasLov()
    }
  }
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

It's a duplication of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518763/set-value-to-text-area-when-button-clicked/58521773#58521773)

"You can assign the text area value at the click action level: inside your button logic add salaryformulaEntity.function = "newValue""

Comment: its work , but this is replacing the next value, i want to append old value with latest value

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the old value with the new one?
(salaryformulaEntity.function = salaryformulaEntity.function + "newValue"")